# How to fix 'wrong number of template arguments' when C++11 enabled'?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have some complex third-party code that uses templates. With gcc 7.3.0 it builds ok if gcc flag -std=gnu++98 is specified, but gives a compilation error otherwise (i.e. with C++11 compilation). I need to fix the C++11 compilation.  Here is the code (sorry it is not complete but the header files are complex):

```
#define CPP11 (__cplusplus > 199711L)

namespace csl
{
namespace PostExec
{

struct Complement
{
    static int64_t Execute(int64_t v)
    {
        return ~v;
    }
};

template<size_t bitWidth, bool maskOutput>
struct Mask
{
    static int64_t Execute(int64_t v)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

#if CPP11
template<typename P, typename... PS>
struct Compound
{
    template<typename T>
    static T&& Execute(T&& v)
    {
        if (sizeof...(PS) > 0)
        {
            return Compound<PS...>::Execute(P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v)));    <<<< COMPILER ERROR HERE
        }
        return P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v));
    }
};
#else
template<typename P1, typename P2>
struct Compound
{
    static int64_t Execute(int64_t v)
    {
        return P1::Execute(P2::Execute(v));
    }
};
#endif

}
}

using namespace csl;
class CModel
{
public:

    void f1();

private:
    void Execute() { }

    static const size_t PAGE_COUNT = 1;

    static size_t CurrentPage;
    static CPage<1, 0> State[PAGE_COUNT];
};

void CModel::f1()
{
    int64_t n[5];
    StepLogicalNXOr<1, false>::Execute(Page.N[1], n[0], n[1]);
}

size_t CModel::CurrentPage = 0;

CPage <1919, 0> CModel::State[PAGE_COUNT] = {
    CPage <1, 0>()    
};
```

The compiler error (when CPP11 is defined) is:

```
<snip>: error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be at least 1)
  return Compound<PS...>::Execute(P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v)));
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<snip>: note: provided for ‘template<class P, class ... PS> struct csl::PostExec::Compound’
struct Compound
       ^~~~~~~~
```

I realise this is complicated but if anyone can help I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with SFINAE?

I mean... something as (caution: code not tested)

```
template<typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<0 != sizeof...(PS), T&&>::type Execute(T&& v)
{ return Compound<PS...>::Execute(P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v))); }


template<typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<0 == sizeof...(PS), T&&>::type Execute(T&& v)
 { return P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v)); }
```

I mean... your code can't works because when `sizeof...(PS) == 0` the row

```
 return Compound<PS...>::Execute(P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v)));
```

is compiled and `Compound` require one ore more template argument; can't accept zero template argument.

I know that this line is under the test

```
if (sizeof...(PS) > 0)
```

but you need `if constexpr`

```
if constexpr (sizeof...(PS) > 0)
```

to avoid the compilation when the test is false; but `if constexpr`, unfortunately, is available only starting from C++17.

So the only solution I see in C++11 is slit the method `Execute()` in two versions and enable/disable the first or the second according the value of `sizeof...(PS)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried your suggested code (your first code block) but now get an error for line iq = PostExec::Compound<PostExec::Mask<bitWidth, maskOutput>, PostExec::Complement>::Execute(BitwiseOps::XOr::Execute(ia, ib));

Comment: The error is: error: call of overloaded ‘Execute(int64_t)’ is ambiguous
     iq = PostExec::Compound<PostExec::Mask<bitWidth, maskOutput>, PostExec::Complement>::Execute(BitwiseOps::XOr::Execute(ia, ib));
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @DavidA - sorry: I've forgotten a `::type` after the `std::enable_if<>` for the second case; I don't know if this is the problem (I don't think so, to be honest) but my first answer is wrong; answer corrected. Can you try with the corrected code?

Comment: The code does compile with that change. Thanks. It seems that, from your comment to ritesh, you believe that your solution is more correct than his?

Comment: @DavidA - yes, because the code you posted, intend (incorrectly) to recursively call `Execute()`, consuming the `Ps...` types; in ritesh's solution, the list of templates never change: is ever `P, Ps...`; so the code compile, but (if I'm not wrong) call itself until reach the recursion limit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm very grateful. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Compound<PS...>::Execute(P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v)));
```

P in the above call is the cause of the problem. 
Compound template takes 2 arguments and only 1 is passed here.

I have tried within all given constraints and I feel that below code should prevent compiler error.

```
template<typename P, typename... PS>
struct Compound
{
    template<typename T>
    static T&& Execute(T&& v)
    {
        if (sizeof...(PS) > 0)
        {
            return Compound<P,PS...>::Execute(P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v)));   
        }
        return P::Execute(std::forward<T>(v));
    }
};
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: prevent the compiler error but doesn't consume the `P, Ps...` list

Comment: Hi Ritesh, thanks for your answer, but it seems that max66's answer is more complete so I have accepted that.